# cannot get an automatic jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set up a link that will be automatically clicked in order to refresh data every ten seconds.. For some reason I just can't seem to get the syntax correct.

If I have a link of

```
<a id="test123" data-remote="true" href="http://www.w3schools.com">test</a>
```

My script is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//<![CDATA[


    $(document).ready(
    function() {
    setInterval(function() {

       $("a#test123").click();

       $("a#test123").trigger("click");
          $("a#test123").after("testing");



        }, 10000);
        });
```

with the code above, 'testing' will appear after my link every ten seconds. However, the link does not execute. I think that means that my jquery, js and ID are correct. However, the link is not automatically clicking either on a test on w3schools 'try it' or when I put it into my page.

Comment: are you trying to refresh the page? use location.reload(). it can be used for an iframe too.

Comment: A simple link does not “refresh data”, it only _links_ somewhere. So presumably the `data-remote="true"` has something to do with it, by triggering some kind of script/functionality – details about which you completely failed to mention. So the reason might as well lay in how that script works, and not really in the clicking of the link itself.

Comment: @CBroe - The final goal was to have a partial in a ruby app update. With Ruby, I can do a link_to that would refresh the partial the way I wanted with a manual click. The ability to do an automated click would allow me to set up a periodic refresh of the partial.

Comment: @stomo21 - My intention was to refresh a partial. location.reload() was refreshing the whole page. However, I was able to use `    $("#refresh3").load(location.href+" #refresh3>*","");` which is just refreshing the partial. This is working better than trying to automate the link click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to invoke `natural click` of that anchor tag,

```
 $("a#test123")[0].click();
```

`jQuery.click()` and `jQuery.trigger()` will only invoke the `event handler` bound with the respective element,  not the natural click.

Comment: That worked. The interesting thing for me was that it would not work if the link referenced a partial. That is OK. Your answer solved the jquery part of my problem.